# Azure Data Factory: Output Copied File and Folder Information from Copy Activity

Tags: azure, copy, azure-data-factory

I'm using the Self-Hosted Integration Runtime in Azure Data Factory to copy data from an On-Premises source (normal file system) to an Azure Blob Storage destination. After being transferred, I want to process the files automatically by attaching a Notebook running on a Databricks cluster. The pipeline works fine, but my question concerns the output of the Copy Activity.

**Is there a way to get information on the transferred files and folders for each run?** I would pass this information as parameters to the notebook.

Looking at the documentation, it seems only aggregated information is available:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview

Which kind of makes sense, if you transfer huge amounts of files. If not possible, I guess an alternate approach would be to just leave the copy process to itself, and create another pipeline based on storage account events? Or maybe store the new file and folder information for each run  in a fixed text file, transfer it also, and read it in the notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually quite simple in this case. I just created another pipeline in Azure Data Factory, which was triggered by a *Blob Created* event, and the **folder** and **filename** passed as parameters to my notebook. Seems to work well, and a minimal amount of configuration or code required. Basic filtering can be done with the event, and the rest is up to the notebook.

For anyone else stumbling across this scenario, details below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get information of files or directories beeing read from data factory this can be done using the Get Metadata Activity, see the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49923091/get-metadata-activity-adf-v2/50199878#50199878) for an example.

Another approach to detect new files in your notebook would be to use structured streaming with file sources. This works pretty well and you just call the notebook activity after the copy activity.

For this you define a streaming input data frame:

```
streamingInputDF = (
   spark
     .readStream                     
     .schema(pqtSchema)               
     .parquet(inputPath) 
 )
```

with *inputPath* pointing to the input dir in the Blob Storage. Supported file formats are text, csv, json, orc, parquet, so it depends on your concrete scenario if this will work for you.

Important is that on the target you use the trigger once option, so the notebook does not need to run pemananently, e. g.:

```
streamingOutputDF \
    .repartition(1) \
    .writeStream \
    .format("parquet") \
    .partitionBy('Id') \
    .option("checkpointLocation", adlpath +  "spark/checkpointlocation/data/trusted/sensorreadingsdelta") \
    .option("path", targetPath + "delta") \
    .trigger(once=True) \
    .start()
```

Another approach could be using Azure Queue Storage (AQS), see the following [documentation](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/structured-streaming/aqs.html#use-the-abs-aqs-file-source).

Comment: I like the idea of using structured streaming. I get CSV files as input, but they vary in schema and are spread out in subfolders. I think I got both figured (infer schema, glob pattern), but I am having a hard time of writing each CSV into a respective table (Hive). I'm using _foreachBatch_ on _writeStream_, but it seems to be picking up all kinds of unrelated files into the same destination table, not just the single one being updated via Data Factory. I'll look further into this, and probably edit the post with details on this specific approach.

Comment: Ok, your scenario seems to be more complicated. Yes, all files in the subdirs will be picked, initially all of them. Phps. you can mix the approach with folders as parameters (for input/output and checkpointing dirs) from data factory?